# You do not have the necessary permissions to access the requested object, or the object can not be read from the server

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I have installed xampp in my computer and I have just done:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./project
```

So all files in my project have 777 permissions.

But when I try to access at a folder that contains css:

```
http://localhost:1580/project/application/css
```

I obtain:

> You do not have the necessary permissions to access the requested object, or the object can not be read from the server.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

When Apache HTTP gets a request for a URL that resolves to a directory it will attempt to find an index file.

It will look through the list of names specified with the [DirectoryIndex directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) and attempt to serve the first one it finds a match for.

You might encounter a permissions problem at this point, but since you've set the file permissions to `777` you shouldn't.

If it doesn't find a match, it may generate a directory listing using [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

It will only do this if [the Options directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) includes `+Indexes`.

---

If your case, it sounds like you don't have an index document (and why would you in amongst the CSS?) and haven't enabled Indexes if your Options.